# Python requests importing proxies

Tags: python, python-requests, proxies

I am trying to create a program to test proxies.  This code should be working but it's not. I am getting the error "requests.exceptions.InvalidURL: Not supported proxy scheme None"

```
import requests
from requests.exceptions import Timeout

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:89.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/89.0',
    'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-GB,en;q=0.5',
    'DNT': '1',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',
}

proxy = {
    "http": "169.57.1.85:80",
    "https": "169.57.1.85:80"
}

proxy_Test = requests.get("https://httpbin.org/", headers=headers, proxies=proxy, timeout=10)
print(proxy_Test.status_code)
if proxy_Test.status_code == 200:
    print("this proxy is good:" + str(proxy).replace("{", " ").replace("}", "").replace("'", ""))
else:
    print("This proxy is no good")
try:
    x = requests.get("http://www.google.com", headers=headers, proxies=proxy, timeout=1)
except Timeout:
    print("error found")
```

Comment: define proxy like this: proxies = {
  'http': 'http://10.10.1.10:3128',
  'https': 'http://10.10.1.10:1080',
}

Comment: I did this but I am now getting "requests.exceptions.InvalidURL: Not supported proxy scheme None"

Comment: [This](https://github.com/psf/requests/issues/5297) might help you with your issue.

Comment: Very strange.  Adding "//" before http and https makes the program work.  However, it always says the response is 200, no matter what proxy you use.  So far nothing on there has resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
import requests
from requests.exceptions import Timeout


headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:89.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/89.0',
    'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-GB,en;q=0.5',
    'DNT': '1',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',
}

proxy = {
    'http':'45.174.70.18:53281',
    'https':'45.174.70.18:53281'
}

proxy_Test = requests.get("https://httpbin.org/", headers=headers, proxies=proxy, timeout=20)
print(proxy_Test.status_code)
if proxy_Test.status_code == 200:
    print("this proxy is good:" + str(proxy).replace("{", " ").replace("}", "").replace("'", ""))
else:
    print("This proxy is no good")
try:
    x = requests.get("http://www.google.com", headers=headers, proxies=proxy, timeout=0.2)
except Timeout:
    print("error found")
```

Comment: There was nothing wrong with my indentation, it's the same as yours.  As far as the proxy scheme I updated it to what you have and still get the error "requests.exceptions.InvalidURL: Not supported proxy scheme None"

Comment: its working . here's the output : `200
this proxy is good: http: 169.57.1.85:80, https: 169.57.1.85:80 `

Comment: What requests version are you using.  Maybe my computer is blocking the proxies for some reason.

Comment: I’m running it on Colab.

Comment: Hmm, well still no lucky with PyCharm.